# Laravel translations in Facebook Open Graph tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I'm trying to set up localized descriptions of Facebook share modal, but I can't get it working with Laravel localization.

When I try to set og:description like this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ \Lang::get('main.fb_share_description') }}" />
```

description shown in share modal is `main.fb_share_description`,
when I try to set a tag explicitly `content="some description"`
it is showing fine.

Website is scraped without errors in Facebook Debugger, except the issue above.

Does anybody know, what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use blade syntax.

`<meta property="og:description" content="@lang('main.fb_share_description')" />`

If that doesn't work, try trans() helper function.

`<meta property="og:description" content="{{ trans('main.fb_share_description') }}"/>`

Comment: I tried that, and still I get key instead of translation. Any use of Laravel translation to pass value to OG tags seems to not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried the trans() helper function? Hit scrape a couple times for good measure.

Comment: Still no luck using trans(). I ended up with writing custom helper class for it, without using laravel translation system, but still I would like to know if there is a solution for this.